# How to open Facebook / Twitter app from my iOS app in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, facebook, twitter, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iOS app with Xamarin, in C#.

I have a "contact" `UIViewController`, with some buttons, including Facebook and Twitter.

I need to open the Facebook and Twitter App with a specific Facebook Page and Twitter profile from my app.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("fb://page/page_id"));
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("twitter://user?user_id=userid"));
```

For `page_id` right click on page and select view source page and find the `page_id` for facebook and same as for twitter find the `userid`

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thanks

Comment: if I have facebook or twitter app installed in my phone, it will ask to open on the app?

Comment: It is application specific URI schemes, when passed through intent it redirects to that specific app if installed.

Comment: What if the device does not have those apps? How do you open the browser instead?

Comment: Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.yourpageurl.com/")); This is the way you can open in browser. Here you need to pass the full url instead of using intent like "fb://" or "twitter://". Intents are used to target the app not browser.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38456760/4053389), 
following are my finding to open links in external applications.
 
To open link in browser:

> Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://example.in/index.html"));

To open group in facebook:

> Device.OpenUri(new Uri("fb://group/groupname"));

To open page in facebook:

> Device.OpenUri(new Uri("fb://page/page_id"));

To open user in instagram:

> Device.OpenUri(new Uri("instagram://user?username=yourUserName"));

To open user in twitter:

> Device.OpenUri(new Uri("twitter://userName?user_id=userId"));

To open mail app:

> Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:example@gmail.com"));

Comment: Please, how can I do the same thing on Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Is it possible to open the app with out "username" and "page_id"

Answer (score 4):

You also can use these methods if you are using Xamarin.Forms:

```
await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("your-link");

await Launcher.TryOpenAsync(new Uri("your-link");

await Launcher.CanOpenAsync(new Uri("your-link");

await Browser.OpenAsync("your-link");
```

As far as I remember, Browser will try to start the url with it's default application, if installed on the phone when you use:

```
BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred
```

Answer (score 1):

For those arriving at this page after me, the [Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.openuri?view=xamarin-forms) class has been deprecated. You should now use the [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=android) class from the [Xamarin.Essentials](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/) package.

Comment: Does it still working for you? I've tried: my Facebook app is opened, but not at the expected page...

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that worked for me in 2022, in both iOS *and* Android. It will open in the Twitter/Facebook apps if they're installed, and in the browser if they're not.

```
private async void OnTwitterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!await Launcher.TryOpenAsync("twitter://user?user_id=762836470772097024"))
    {
        await Browser.OpenAsync("https://twitter.com/RingotanApp");
    }
}

private async void OnFacebookClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!await Launcher.TryOpenAsync("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/RingotanApp"))
    {
        await Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.facebook.com/RingotanApp");
    }
}
```

In iOS, you also need to add the following to `Info.plist`

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

---

I used [this tool](https://codeofaninja.com/tools/find-twitter-id/) to find my numeric Twitter ID.

Another URI option for Facebook is `"fb://page/1761091624175851"`, where the numeric ID comes from "About --> More Info" on Facebook.  However, this URI was janky for me - it would first open the page in the app normally, then switch to the web modal used by `facewebmodal`. I recommend not using it.