# Xamarin Forms open another iOS App

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms App I want to open another App by clicking a button. The example is with the facebook app, but it should work with other apps, too. I read a lot about this [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/launching-mobile-app-via-uri-scheme/) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48089/how-to-open-other-apps-from-xamarin-forms). Based on the two solutions/links I generated a class in my iOS project:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(OpenAppiOS))]
namespace FieldServicePortable.iOS.Common
{
    public class OpenAppiOS : IOpenApp
    {
        public OpenAppiOS() { }

        public void OpenExternalApp()
        {
            var nsurl = "facebook://";
            var request = new NSUrl(nsurl);

            try
            {
                var isOpened = UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request);   //Open App
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also extended the `Info.plist` by this lines

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
   <string>facebook</string>
</array>
```

I don't want to bother you with the coding part in the shared projects, because this part works.

After clicking the button in the app, the code will be executed but nothing happens. Not even an exception is thrown. The value of the variable `isOpened` is `false`.

So my questions are:

1. Of course, do I miss something in my code?
2. Are there any requirements for the App, which should be open?
3. Is some configuration needed in the iOS?

Comment: FYI its called deep linking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using
    `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("fb://"));`

Also you can refer [xamarin how to open facebook and twitter app from my ios app by a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456618/xamarin-how-to-open-facebook-and-twitter-app-from-my-ios-app-by-a-button)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I tested it and it works fine. But where did you find this URI, because I also want to open other apps for example "Anveo Mobile"?

Comment: So finally I downloaded the App with iMazing and unziped the .ipa and looked in the info.plist for "CFBundleURLSchemes". Thats the name I was looking for. :)